# GitLab CI - passing variable into $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE

Tags: variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am able to trigger my pipeline from a hardcoded commit message e.g:

rules:

- if: ‘$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /some commit message/’

however I want to use a project level variable (settings>CI>Variable) as the commit message e.g

rules:

- if: ‘$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /$RELEASE_ID/’

this doesn’t kick off the pipeline despite the commit message on the file matching the variable. Nor do the following:

```
- if: ‘$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /{$RELEASE_ID}/’
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /"$RELEASE_ID"/' 
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == $RELEASE_ID'
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == "$RELEASE_ID"'
```

Is this even doable?

```
- if: ‘$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /{$RELEASE_ID}/’
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /"$RELEASE_ID"/' 
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == $RELEASE_ID'
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == "$RELEASE_ID"'
```

...I have since tried Egor's suggestion to put the exp in the variable itself.  so I added /1.0.1/ into my variable.   This works only if I specific the 1.0.1 in the commits and nothing else - it doesn't work if the commit contains other text.   I've tried /1.0.1/gi but still not luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [store regex in a variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#store-the-regex-pattern-in-a-variable) ([available](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/359740) by default from GitLab 15.3). So in your case, you can set `RELEASE_ID` variable with value `/.*0\.0\.9.*/` in Settings and then use this variable in `gitlab-ci` file:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $RELEASE_ID
```

GitLab uses the following [regex syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

In earlier versions regex variables [will be evaluated as strings](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35438)  by default.

Comment: hi - thanks for the help.  unfortunately that didn't work.  and I tried a few variations on that while I was at it.

Comment: so I added /1.0.1/ into my variable. This works only if I specific the 1.0.1 in the commits and nothing else - it doesn't work if the commit contains other text. I've tried /1.0.1/gi but still not luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hm, strange, it works on my side. Maybe it depends on GitLab version. I have updated the answer with new regex.

Comment: Also it is important that this feature is available from 15.3 GitLab version.

Comment: ahh, that'll be it.  i'm on 14.   really appreciate the help though.  thanks